# Find all .htaccess files in all user sub-directories and add a string to it

Tags: bash, .htaccess, shell, findandmodify

I want to find all ".htaccess" files (if the file exist, if not create one) for all user accounts in  a whole string of possible sub-directories underneath "public_html" (but not public_html). Basically find it in anything that remotely resembles a directory that may contain images.

Here is my code:

```
#!/bin/bash 
cat /etc/domainusers | cut -f1 -d: | while read USER; do
find /home/$USER/public_html/ -type d -regex ".*\/public_html\/.*\(img.\|pic.\|pics.\|image.\|images.\|Image.\|Images.\|Pic.\|Pics.\|Img.\|picture.\|pictures.\|Picture.\|Pictures.\|upload.\|Upload.\|download.\|Download.\|Gallery\|gallery\|Galleries\|galleries\|import.\|Import.\|Thumbnail.\|Thumbnails.\|thumbnail.\|thumbnails.\|wpThumbnail.\|thumb.\|Thumb.\)" | while read FOLDER; 
    do
        if [[ -e "$FOLDER/.htaccess" && ! $(grep "AddHandler cgi-script" "$FOLDER/.htaccess") ]]; then
            echo -e "AddHandler cgi-script .php .pl .py .jsp .asp .htm .html .shtml .sh .cgi .php5 .php4 .php3 .phps .txt .bat .cmd .rb .txt .msi .exe .xml .xhtml\nOptions -ExecCGI -Indexes" >> "$FOLDER/.htaccess"
            chattr +ia "$FOLDER/.htaccess"
        fi
    done
done
```

Although the above script runs ok, it does not actually do what I want it to do. I checked a user's image directory and didn't find any ".htaccess" file there. :/

Ideally, I would also like to see on the screen what it is going on during the execution, and, if possible, also output the result to a text file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For debugging purposes you can use the command `set -xv` (you can put it under the `#!/bin/bash`).

For the script not writing any .htaccess I think the culprit is in your if statement:

your conditions state that if .htaccess exists and does not contain "AddHandler cgi-script" then you can do something, but if the file .htaccess does not exists the if condition exit without doing anything

try this:

```
if [[ ! -e "$FOLDER/.htaccess" || ! $(grep "AddHandler cgi-script" "$FOLDER/.htaccess") ]]
```

So if the file exists it will add the "AddHandler cgi-script" and if the file doesn't exist it will create it with the requested string

Comment: It worked!! Thank you so much @Diego
:)
I ran it with the modified code, checked a couple of image directories and the file was there!

Now to figure out how to write the results to a text file in order to keep track of what was done.

Comment: you're welcome, focus your efforts on output redirecting, if you work frequently with bash the Advanced Bash Scripting Guide (here the link http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/abs-guide.pdf) is your friend :-)